# executing method of a class that extends an abstract class

Tags: typescript, oop

I have encountered this example from Typescript site:

```
abstract class Department {

    constructor(public name: string) {
    }

    printName(): void {
        console.log("Department name: " + this.name);
    }

    abstract printMeeting(): void; // must be implemented in derived classes
}

class AccountingDepartment extends Department {

    constructor() {
        super("Accounting and Auditing"); // constructors in derived classes must call super()
    }

    printMeeting(): void {
        console.log("The Accounting Department meets each Monday at 10am.");
    }

    generateReports(): void {
        console.log("Generating accounting reports...");
    }
}

let department: Department; // ok to create a reference to an abstract type
department = new Department(); // error: cannot create an instance of an abstract class
department = new AccountingDepartment(); // ok to create and assign a non-abstract subclass
department.printName();
department.printMeeting();
**department.generateReports();** // error: method doesn't exist on declared abstract type???
```

I have 2 questions regarding this:

1. why this line is not valid ? department has access to generateReports() since it's type is also Acounting Department. I have run this code and it indeed executes department.generateReports() with no problem
2. when I am doing `department = new Department();` although this is a mistake to create an instance of an abstract class it doesnt give me a runtime error. Why is this happening ? Is this is my responsibility to not create an instance of an abstract class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `department` is *declared* to be a `Departement`, this means that even if it *could* be an `AccountingDepartement`, it's not assured to be. Just think about that:

   ```
   let department: Department;
   // ...
   department = departmentName === 'accounting'
     ? new AccountingDepartment()
     : new CustomerCareDepartment();
   // ...
   department.generateReports(); // You really can't know if it's available
   ```

   If you just typed `let department = new AccountingDepartment();` it would have been ok, since TS infers type and declares `department` as an `AccountingDepartment`
2. Abstract classes are a TypeScript feature, not JS, so when TS is transpiled to JS, the `abstract` keyword is just removed. You will get errors at compile time, like most of the TypeScript features, not at compile time. See a transpilation example here: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/E4ewrgLgpsB0DmUIAoBEB6VAaABAMzADsBjCASxEJ2WCgEddaBnAShwG8AoHHnAGyQ4wwMjgC8OAOQALCBAAOALnTo+IYgEM+0kEwiKAzAAYT6DfLLoAbgEZ0AE0obylJpIDcnbrwEQcAfTISPjB7KH9pKA0w4CZxfCJSCipkACMQewBPRigmeVcoHKYQPisoAHUyCGkAMTA+PgAlXPzCJig2Ll5unFoIYSp2KUjomDdFXpaC2BGYplxJe2cNSQn0rJwAX09u7a9u3xwQeRc2+K6engBbJB17CckAcQBRABVJLG9L4TIJn8-LjwAFbFQgTCDAMCFL49CEaNp4EDAK4TQLBULhWZjAG8Tb7Xh9AaTOhQvTIY6nVgw7qwapQQjIAgkU7UZitdqdamA4iuEpQWBqeA0KZtflY2IsHaA7o8tp8gUgIVs6ZLCAaSVcnibDXa9xAA)